# In which cases is considered requiring to have a registered account to post on a Stack Exchange site a necessity?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

As far as I recall, *Stack Overflow* requires users to have a registered account to post. (I don't remember if that is true for answers, questions, or both.)
In which cases is this considered also for other Stack Exchange sites? Is the number of recent spam post a reason sufficient for changing the setting of a Stack Exchange site, and require a registered account to post?

I am asking because on *Drupal Answers* (the site where I am one of the moderators), I noticed a increment of spam posts, in the last months. I have noticed that spammers started to use also questions to post spam, which seems a silly way to spam, as it is immediately visible from the front page when a post is purely spam. (I know, spammers are not smart, but that is a different story. `;)`)

Comment: Ah yeah, [spam on drupal.se](https://twitter.com/df07/status/300250817473175552) :)

Comment: Programmers turned it on in an attempt to reduce the number of "bad" questions they get, but [it didn't really help at all](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5377/1130)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requiring registration for asking a question doesn't significantly slow down SPAM, at least not on Stack Overflow, though I suppose you could say it is a minor speed bump.

Requiring registration more prevents people that ask questions from easily (and unwittingly) becoming disenfranchised from them. Symptoms of this include:

- Posting edits to questions as answers
- Needing to suggest edits to their own questions
- Being unable to comment, thus posting more non answers

Those are the problems that requiring registration solves.

I'm not at all suggesting that the requirement should be forever specific to Stack Overflow, but SPAM is better handled by the community and moderation team. I wouldn't want to put a barrier (or speed bump) in front of people that want to ask legitimate questions unless the symptoms of not doing so are rather rampant at an appreciably large scale.

Comment: Effectively, we had that problem too: users who used multiple unregistered accounts, or a registered account and an unregistered account. It is not something that was so evident, IMO, and it it less evident than the SPAM, probably because users don't notice when the same person is using two accounts.

Comment: And that's just it - it's like all of a sudden one day everyone notices how much more (major emphasis on more) work lost cookies has been adding to the janitorial workflow, at which time it may be worth evaluating. For really targeted SPAM, a more .. surgical ... solution might be in order. Registration would barely slow them down, it's just too cheap and easy to get humans to create bulk lots of accounts.

Comment: And since moderators cannot anymore merge accounts, when a user has multiple accounts, I cannot merge them to avoid the OP writes again as answer what should be a comment for an answer, or an edit for a question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: when you see that, please *let us know*. We badly want to improve that process without requiring moderators to babysit the folks' creating accounts, and to do that we need to *know about it*. Thanks!

Comment: @Shog9 There isn't much to say: There have been users who used two different accounts with the same display name, and the same avatar, that tried commenting for an answer given to a question asked with their other account, or edit a question created with an account when using the other account. I am glad of not baby sitting users, but in this case it's just a human who can understand if a user is using two accounts, I guess. I would also be happy if there would be a way to report that a user is using two accounts, even if it is somebody/something else that take cares of what to do.